# Angular2: @ContentChild - only immediate children

Tags: angular

So for better illustration will simplify and try to be as concise as possible.

```ts
<my-accordion>
    <my-title>My accordion</my-title>

    <my-accordion-item>
        <my-title>My accordion item 1</my-title>
        <my-content>Content 1</my-content>
    <my-accordion-item>
    <my-accordion-item>
        <my-title>My accordion item 2</my-title>
        <my-content>Content 2</my-content>
    <my-accordion-item>
</my-accordion>
```

As you can see, I use (my) standard my-title for my-accordion and my-accordion-item

So in my-accordion component I have the logic

```ts
private title:string = '';
@ContentChild( myTitle ) myTitle: myTitle;

ngAfterViewInit(){
    if(this.myTitle && this.myTitle.content.length !== 0){
        this.title = this.myTitle.content;
    }
}
```

So, if I had my view exactly like in my previous example, it works OK.... and the title coming back is "**My accordion**" but, if I don't have the my-title element on the root of my-accordion....like this:

```ts
<my-accordion>        
    <my-accordion-item>
        <my-title>My accordion item 1</my-title>
        <my-content>Content 1</my-content>
    <my-accordion-item>
    <my-accordion-item>
        <my-title>My accordion item 2</my-title>
        <my-content>Content 2</my-content>
    <my-accordion-item>
</my-accordion>
```

The title would be set to "**My accordion item 1**", because it gets the first my-title in the whole DOM sub tree

Is there a way to just check immediate children?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`@ContentChild()` doesn't but `@ContentChildren()` does
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ContentChildren-decorator.html

```ts
@ContentChildren( myTitle, {descendants: false}) myTitle: QueryList<myTitle>;

ngAfterContentInit() {
  console.log(this.myTitle.toArray()[0]);
}
```

See also [angular 2 / typescript : get hold of an element in the template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/angular-2-typescript-get-hold-of-an-element-in-the-template/35209681#35209681)